# Can we trigger AWS Lambda function from aws Glue PySpark job?

Tags: pyspark, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Currently i'm able to run `Glue PySpark job`, but is this possible to call a `lambda function` from `Glue` this job ? Using below code from my `PySpark` Glue job i'm calling lambda function.

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-west-2')
response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='test-lambda')
```

**Error:**

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke operation: User: arn:aws:sts::208244724522:assumed-role/AWSGlueServiceRoleDefault/GlueJobRunnerSession is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:208244724522:function:hw-test

But I added proper lambda roles to my Glue iam role, still getting above error. Any specific role need to add ?

Thanks.

Comment: I saw few links where this is not possible. Thats why raised a question here.

Comment: can you share IAM role and policy?

Comment: Below two roles attached to my Gluedefault role id :  AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke AWS Lambda you can use the following [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.LambdaCreatePolicy.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToExampleFunction",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<123456789012>:function:<example_function>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your roles are not suitable for Lambda invocations as

> **AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole** – Grants permissions only for the Amazon CloudWatch Logs actions to write logs. You can use this policy
>   if your Lambda function does not access any other AWS resources except
>   writing logs.
>
> **AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole** – Grants permissions for Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) actions to manage elastic network
>   interfaces (ENIs).

Please see documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html) about these roles.

Comment: Yes Thanks.

AWSLambdaRole also can be used instead.